# Pie chart: format value and percent independly

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to format the DataLabel of a chart with thousands separator (dot) and two decimals in the percentage. Something like: "1.500; 66,66%".

Recording a macro I see that the NumberFormat for dot as thousands separator is: `_-* #,##0_-;-* #,##0_-;_-* ""-""??_-;_-@_-` but I cannot format the DataLabels with it since then the percentage won't show up correctly.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select    
With ActiveChart
Call .SetSourceData(v_range)
.ChartType = xl3DPie
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = p_title
.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
End With
With Selection
.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
.ShowPercentage = True
.Separator = "" & Chr(10) & ""
.ShowLegendKey = 0
End With
```

**Edit:**
I think I need to clarify my problem. I'm creating this piechart automaticaly with a range my data, for example the count of A and the count of B, and I'm showing also the percentage, which the chart calculates. In the data range there are only A,B and the corresponing counts. What I have now can be seen in the image bellow.

[image: Piechart I have now]

What I wanted is this:

[image]

If there is no way to do it just with formating I guess i have to 'manually' calculate the percentage and 'manually' write the label with it. By manually I mean to access the `SeriesCollections(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Text = number + "\n" + percentage` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is to edit each point's label and insert the percentage yourself.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
With ActiveChart
Call .SetSourceData(v_range)
.ChartType = xl3DPie
.SeriesCollection(1).Name = p_title
.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Text = Format(countA, "#,##") & Chr(10) &   Format(countA / (countA + countB), "0.00%")
.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).DataLabel.Text = Format(countB, "#,##") & Chr(10) & Format(countB / (countA + countB), "0.00%")
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the data labels option to display the value *and* series name/etc., then you can most likely simply format the *source* data cells.

Right-click the cells, apply whatever format you need, or simply apply the format to the *range* of cells in your macro, e.g.:

```
Range("A1:A10").NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0_-;-* #,##0_-;_-* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
```

**Note** my system locale uses the `,` as the thousands separator and as the delimiter in the labels. Your locale uses the `.` separator and `;` delimter then I think this should work.

[image]